# Imitate UINavigationController's animations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, xamarin.ios

I'm looking for a way to remove an existing `UIViewController` and add a new one.
I would like to animate that the same way as `UINavigationController` does it.

Why do I not want to use UINavigationController then?

- I don't need any of the toolbars or navigation items
- I do not need the `UINavigationController`'s awareness of its history (= the stack of pushed controllers)

It must be possible with `CATransition` but how the heck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook up to ViewWillAppear method and use CoreAnimation to transition your view into the screen.

Comment: That's an even better idea to what I have come up today! I'm using core animation but did not think of hooking up to ViewWillAppear and *Disappear. Thanks for the hint!